# Is it ok to use empty methods as "semi-abstract" method? (PhP)

Tags: java, php, oop

see a money class:

```
abstract class Money
{
    private $value;

    public abstract function getName();

    public function show()
    {
         static::announceOutput();
         return 'output: '.$this->value.' ('.$this->getName().')');
    }

    public function announceOutput() { }
}
```

and some implementation

```
class Dollar extends Money
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return '$';
    }
}

class Huf extends Money
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'HUF';
    }
}

class Font extends Money
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'L';
    }

    public function announceOutput()
    {
        return 'Font is outputted, its name is miswritten';
    }
}
```

I know its not a lifelike example though. What I want to show is:

- `getName()` is different in each valute so it must be abstract and be
  overwritten 100%
- `show()` its pointless to implement in every class - it is outputted
  like that in case every value
- `announceOutput()` well here comes the interesting part. The valute may
  decide to overwrite it or not, so it doesnt have to be abstract.
  Still, if it were, in every class there would be tons of empty
  announceOutput() method. So its like a semi-abstract class, but its
  not likely to be overwritten.

My question is, it is a sign that Im doing something not OK?

Comment: In that case, you should be using an interface rather than an abstract class to define that "children" must implement a specified method with a specified signature

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you should be using an interface rather than an abstract class to define that "children" must implement a specified method with a specified signature

```
interface MoneyName
{
    public function getName();
}

abstract class Money
{
    private $value;

    public function show()
    {
         static::announceOutput();
         return 'output: '.$this->value.' ('.$this->getName().')');
    }

    public function announceOutput() { }
}

class Dollar extends Money implements MoneyName
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return '$';
    }
}
```

You can also implement multiple interfaces

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sign that you're doing anything wrong. What is happening here is that the Abstract Class is providing the basic behaviour for a method, while still allowing any of its children to overrule this default behaviour with their own implementation.

You are probably being thrown off because the default behaviour for `announceOutput()` method in your example has no body, which makes it look strange. It would look perfectly normal if there was actual code in there.

However, as mentioned in the Comments, you *could* also fix this with an Interface. Whether that would be any better depends on the context. In your example, this seems to be perfectly workable.